# How to separate elements in a list to put them as value in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, set

I want to display words that have the required character in a dictionary. For example :

```
Write a sentence: Mister Jack, you are a good coder

{'a': ['are', 'jack,'], 'b': [], 'c': ['coder', 'jack,'], 'd': ['coder'], 'e': ['coder', 'mister',], 'f': [], 'g': [], 'h': [], 'i': ['mister'], 'j': ['jack,'], 'k': ['jack,'], 'l': [], 'm': ['mister', ], 'n': [], 'o': ['coder', 'you', 'good'], 'p': [], 'q': [], 'r': ['coder', 'mister'], 's': ['mister', ], 't': ['mister'], 'u': ['you'], 'v': [], 'w': [], 'x': [], 'y': ['you'], 'z': []}
```

Here is my code :

```py
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
sentence= (input("Write your sentence: " )).lower()
letter_notfound=(sorted(list((set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set("".join(sentence.split()))))))
print (letter_notfound)

letter_list=list(alphabet)
unique_letter = (sorted(list((set(letter_list)-set(letter_notfound)))))

dico={}

for key in (letter_list):
    for char in sentence:
        if char in unique_letter:
         dico[char] = [sentence]
    for char in letter_notfound:
        dico[char] = []
print(dict(sorted(dico.items())))
```

Input: Mister Jack, you are a good coder

Output:

```json
{'a': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'b': [], 'c': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'd': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'e': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'f': [], 'g': ['mister jack, you are 
a good coder'], 'h': [], 'i': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'j': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'k': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'l': [], 'm': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'n': [], 'o': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'p': [], 'q': [], 'r': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 's': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 't': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'u': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'v': [], 'w': [], 'x': [], 'y': ['mister jack, you are a good coder'], 'z': []}
```

Desired output:

```json
{'a': ['are', 'jack,'], 'b': [], 'c': ['coder', 'jack,'], 'd': ['coder'], 'e': ['coder', 'mister',], 'f': [], 'g': [], 'h': [], 'i': ['mister'], 'j': ['jack,'], 'k': ['jack,'], 'l': [], 'm': ['mister', ], 'n': [], 'o': ['coder', 'you', 'good'], 'p': [], 'q': [], 'r': ['coder', 'mister'], 's': ['mister', ], 't': ['mister'], 'u': ['you'], 'v': [], 'w': [], 'x': [], 'y': ['you'], 'z': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

More 'Pythonic' to use list/dictionary [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
words = sentence.split(' ') # Assuming already lowercase
alphabet_dict = {x: [w for w in words if x in w] for x in ascii_lowercase}
```

Comprehensions are not just more concise but are more *declarative* rather than *imperative*, and so in most cases are easier to understand as it more readily states the *what* rather than the *how*.

I recommend reading [When to Use a List Comprehension in Python](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

Comment: Nice job,, I agree list comprehension is a good answer

Answer (score 0):

This makes a dictionary with the alphabet and then turns input into a list separated by words. Then we loop over the letters and check if it is in the alphabet dictionary if so we append the word.

```py
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet_dict = {alphabet[i]: [] for i in range(len(alphabet))}
input_list = input("Enter a string: ").split(" ")
for word in input_list:
    for letter in word:
        if letter in alphabet_dict:
            alphabet_dict[letter].append(word)
alphabet_dict = dict(sorted(alphabet_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))
print(alphabet_dict)
```

Comment: Two things - alphabet is a `str` which is `iterable`, you can just iterate over it letter by letter. And `split` creates list ;)

Comment: How can I make the value of the dictionnary sorted ? For exemple, how do I go from      'o': ['world'],['hello'] to 'o': ['hello'],['world'] ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would recommend is to iterate through words, as only them are important for you. You can get them with `split`

```
words = sentence.split()
```

Second thing is you nowhere append new word to existing key. You should start with preparing the dict.

```
dico = {letter: [] for letter in alphabet}
```

Now it should be easy to check if letter is in word.

```
for letter im letter_list:
    for word in words:
        if letter in word:
            dico[letter].append(word)
```